# Honda civic se sedan automatic immobilizer proplem

Tags: honda, civic, immobilizer

I removed the car's battery for 5 minutes, now the green light stays on with the key and the car won't start.

had it checked by an auto mechanic without finding a solution.

If I install a used ECU, MICU, and locks with a key from the same car will I solve the problem?

Comment: Look in your owner's manual to learn how to restore the immobilizer after the battery has been disconnected. If you do not have an owner's manual, find it online.